# Windows 8.1 keeps making device unplugged and connected sounds

Tags: windows-8.1

The title basically says it all. Windows 8.1 makes these plug-in and unplug sounds all the time with about 5 min. intervals, I think.

Is there maybe some software out there that can monitor what gets plugged in and/or out because I couldn't find anything in the Windows' Event log.

EDIT: <strike>This question has been "answered", it seems only an update of miscellaneous components was necessary.</strike>

The updates I did only seemed to help for a day or so, and I have not been able to find a permanent fix in the mean time.
The question is still open for answers (and so are my ears).

After trying to debug a little bit with an application called USBView from Microsoft I found out that I have one USB device that posts a "DeviceGeneralFaliure" on [Loc1f] which I don't have a clue of what is.
Also, the application crashes when the device unplugged sound plays, which I find interesting.
My graphics card driver from nVidia (the latest beta one 331.93) crashes sometimes too.

Most likely last EDIT: I unplugged the USB header for my Corsair H100i, and didn't hear the sound since. I will be taking this subject to their customer service then but this will hang for a little bit.

Comment: Check all your connections, any loose cords may be causing this. There could also be a problem with your computers USB plugs (try using a different one) or with one of the connected devices.

Comment: I tried to disconnect all three of my connected USB devices, keyboard mouse and a USB passthrough, nothing worked; the sound has escalated to once every 10-15 seconds, it is REALLY f'ing annoying. I'm trying to update sound card and graphics card drivers right now.

Comment: I used "Live Update 5" (MSI's updating software and updated what could be updated, and I havent heard the sound since, though thanks for the comment.

Comment: Hey, screw that old comment, didn't last for long

Comment: I am more sure of the problem being caused by something bad on my H100i, it's only that USB device which makes Windows go all nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tool called [EventGhost](https://github.com/EventGhost/EventGhost) answers this question cleanly and immediately. It's not specifically made for this task, but it's the best, cleanest solution to this very-real problem I've found yet. While it's running, all activity gets logged in the left sidebar. This includes laser-precision information about device arrival and disconnection -- the events that trigger the sounds.

With the knowledge of the device IDs being triggered, you can browse through the Device Manager to find the matching device ID in the Details->Hardware IDs box. You may want to use View->"Devices by connection" in order to drill down to the specific part, too.

Screenshot of EventGhost

[image]

This problem has bugged me for years -- the ambiguity of the device arrival/device disconnect sounds -- and I'm glad I finally found a solution I can pass along!

Comment: Thanks for answering this age old question. The computer in question has long since been retired. I'll mark is accepted and maybe it can help someone else :)