# Receiving a 'Device Disconnect" chime and need to find the device

Tags: windows

I am receiving a device disconnect chime about every 30 seconds. When I go to the device manager I can see the devices list updating coincident with the chime. Is there a way to determine which device is connecting-disconnecting? It would seem the only alternative would be to expand the display and watch each device group hoping to see the change.

OS: Windows 8.1

USB Devices:
Mouse - Kensington trackball
Keyboard: Microsoft
Printer: HP Officejet 6600

Comment: First of all, unplug any external device and check if you still get the same behavior. Then you could use an utility such as [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/en-us) or [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) to get a list of the available devices. By generating multiple lists at different times you should be able to pinpoint the device that's not working correctly.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please edit your question to indicate what version of Windows you are running and provide a list of USB peripherals you have connected to your computer. Welcome and good luck.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/676691/windows-8-1-keeps-making-device-unplugged-and-connected-sounds